# When I download an image it doesn't go to my gallery

Tags: photos, gallery, google-photos

I'm trying to customise my phone a little better and I want to download some images but when I click download they don't end up in my photos even though they say they have downloaded. I'm pretty sure that in the past when downloading images into my phone they went into my gallery but now they ok just disappear! Does anyone know how to change this? (My device is a moto 7 plus I think)

Comment: Downloaded images are usually store in the Downloads folder, not in the Images folder.

Comment: The problem is they are not there either